# "manage categories" error message

Tags: category

when i was trying to enter "manage categories" i have got this error :

> a:5:{i:0;s:138:"Source model "mttheme/system_config_source_category_attribute_source_block_proportions" not found for attribute "mtmenu_proportions_right"";i:1;s:4129:"#0 /home/sajidatcp/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')

---

what i have to do to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

you have an attribute (dropdown or multiselect) that is missing the source model.
Most probably this was added by an extension that you later removed or disabled.
you should delete the attribute.
Run this query on your database:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute where source_model = 'mttheme/system_config_source_category_attribute_source_block_proportions'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work!